# Recursive query in MySql to Determine Inheritance type

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have table with information regarding variable data types. Called `inheritance` table, with columns `derived` and `base` and following sample data;

```
derived | base

 Double | Number
 Int    | Number
 Int64  | Int
 Number | Object
```

As seen there can be some base data types which also belong to derived column. But there is guaranteed to be no cyclic dependencies. My goal is to get output as two columns, `derived`, and `base` where `base` column is the final root base element for the corresponding derived type.

For instance, `Int64` has base as `Int`. I am trying to use Recursion with MySql version>8.0. Here is my attempt;

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
SELECT 
derived,
base 
 
FROM inheritance 

UNION ALL

SELECT

inheritance.derived,
inheritance.base
FROM inheritance,hierarchy
WHERE inheritance.derived = hierarchy.base)

SELECT *
FROM hierarchy;
```

It seems there is an error in my terminating condone, hence I get following error;

`ERROR 3636 (HY000) at line 715: Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.`.

Please note that this is only sample data, hence I am trying to write a general recursive query. Help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: I tested what you showed, but I get no error. I am using MySQL 8.0.21. What exact version are you using?

Comment: I would guess you have different data than the four rows of sample data you show, and you may have a cycle in your inheritance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should not generate such error; you probably have a circular dependency in your data, that you will need to fix first.

Then, you seem to want:

```
with recursive hierarchy as (
    select derived, base, 1 lvl from inheritance
    union all
    select h.derived, i.base, h.lvl + 1
    from hierarchy h
    inner join inheritance i on i.derived = h.base
)
select derived, base
from hierarchy h
where lvl = (select max(h1.lvl) from hierarchy h1 where h1.derived = h.derived)
```

Rationale:

- you want to keep track of the original `derived` as you climb up the hierarchy
- the recursive query generates one row per intermediate level; additional logic is needed in the outer query to retain the "deepest" parent only

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f62e2b4e52342021af5d259d4086cb9)** with both your original query and the new query

Comment: @GMB Appreciate your response. It makes sense. I was wondering, if I want to modify for only those rows where base is `Number`, can I just filter in the outer query, rather than taking deepest level. Can you kindly confirm?